# code command to open files in new tab, NOT new window

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I run code command, for example "code test.yaml", it opens "test.yaml" in a new window. See below
[See the behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0HpR.png)

I want to open it in a new tab. (in the example above, to open it next to "commands.txt").

I am looking for some guidance on how to have the files specified via "code" command opened in a new tab, not a new window.

This is how I have my related settings:

[See my settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMcmB.png)

I also tried to use "code --reuse-window test.yaml" but it didn't help, it still opened in a new window.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541 and  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson

Answer (score 0):

Use `code --remote wsl+Ubuntu-22.04 --reuse-window test.yaml`, just replace the wsl distribution name with yours